# Difficulty in testing Angularjs controller with service as its dependency

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have written an angular test application.Trying to learn testing using it.

Controller looks like this

```
var EmployeeModule = EmployeeModule || {};

(function (currentModule) {
    EmployeeModule.EmployeeController = function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, Employees) {
        this.RegEmployees = Employees.GetEmployees();
        this.currentEmployee = {};
        if ($routeParams.Id != undefined) {

          console.log("to check $route"+$routeParams);
          this.currentEmployee = Employees.GetEmployeeById($routeParams.Id);
        }
        this.Id = "";
        this.firstname = "";
        this.lastname = "";
        this.email = "";
        this.dob = "";
        this.department = "";
        this.RegisterEmployee = function () {
            Employees.RegisterEmployee(this.firstname, this.lastname, this.email, this.dob, this.department);
            if ($scope.employeeForm.$valid)
                $location.path("/Employees");
        }
 EmployeeModule.Employee = function (firstname, lastname, email, dob, department) {
        this.Id = Date.now();
        this.FirstName = firstname;
        this.LastName = lastname;
        this.Email = email;
        this.DOB = dob;
        this.Department = department;
    }

})(EmployeeModule);
```

and my angular service looks as this

```
var app = angular.module('angularApp2App');
app.factory('Employees', function () {
    var RegEmployees = {};
    var Employees = [];
    //Service
    RegEmployees.RegisterEmployee = function (firstname, lastname, email, dob, department) {
        var newEmployee = new EmployeeModule.Employee(firstname, lastname, email, dob, department);

        Employees.push(newEmployee);

    }
return RegEmployees;
});
app.controller('EmployeeController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'Employees', EmployeeModule.EmployeeController]);
```

I am trying to write unit tests for the controller,but not sure, how can i inject service as the dependency to the controller in unit testing.

Please help in this
and my code for unit-testing is

```
describe('Controller: EmployeeController', function () {

    // load the controller's module
    beforeEach(module('angularApp2App'));

    var empCtrl,
        scope;

    // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $injector) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        var employeeService = $injector.get('Employees');
        console.log(employeeService);
        spyOn(employeeService , 'RegisterEmployee');
        empCtrl = $controller('EmployeeController', {
            $scope: scope
                // place here mocked dependencies
        });
    }));


    it('checking default values', function () {
        expect(empCtrl.currentEmployee).toEqual({});
    });

    it('checking RegisterEmployee Method',function () {
      expect(RegisterEmployee).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Please, specify your current code for unit tests in the question.

Comment: updated with testing logic,but not sure if thats the right approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you only need to inject the `service` when you want to mock or test that something as called on the service. If that's not the case, angular will automatic inject that for you. I will write here a small test to help you with a insight:

```
describe('Controller: EmployeeController', function () {

    // load the controller's module
    beforeEach(module('angularApp2App'));

    it('Check that Employees.GetEmployees was called on startup', inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, Employees) {
        //Here I am spying on Employees.GetEmployees. It means that the call 
        //to this method will be replaced with an empty function(){}
        //(i.e. nothing will happen). And also means that I can check if
        //it was called and with as parameters (and many other things)
        spyOn(Employees, 'GetEmployees');

        //This initializes the controller
        var myController = $controller('EmployeeController', {
            $scope: $rootScope.$new()
            //You don't need to inject Employees here. It will be automatic
            //injected for you.
        });

        expect(Employees.GetEmployees).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
});
```